# CKQuery with Todays Date

Tags: cloudkit, ckquery

Would really value some support.

I am designing an tvOS app which displays certain CloudKit content in a tableView, the data is different depending on the current date.

Each calendar date correspondents to the data within that Type.

e.g. RecordType "A13032019" relates to 13th March 2019.

I generate the date in the correct format using a func fired within ViewDidLoad (generateDate():

*

> func generateDate() {
>
> ```
>     let formatter = DateFormatter()
>     //2016-12-08 03:37:22 +0000
>     formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy"
>     let now = Date()
>     let dateString = formatter.string(from:now)
>     NSLog("%@", dateString)
>
>   let generateOperationalDate = ("A\(dateString)")
>
>     print(generateOperationalDate)
> }
> ```

I then try to use generateOperationalData to run in the below CKQuery:

> func queryDatabase() {
>
> ```
>     let query = CKQuery(recordType: "\(generateDate())", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
>     let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "trainDepartureTime", ascending: true)
>
>
>     query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
>
>
>     database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, _) in
>
>
>         guard let records = records else { return }
>
>         let sortedRecords = records
> ```

When I try to run this it throws a Thread Error with reason "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'recordType can not be empty'
*** "

So it appears to me that the queryDatabase function is running before the generateDate function, however I have tried delaying the queryDatabase function and this still throws the same error!

Is there anyway I can generate the date (via generateDate) before the queryDatabase function runs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to write generateDate() so it returns a String. Then, inside queryDatabase(), call generateDate() so you're guaranteed to have a value to pass to "recordType".

I also condensed the calls a little bit. Hope this helps.

```
func generateDate() -> String {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from:Date())

    return "A\(dateString)"
}


func queryDatabase() {

    // this will make sure you have a String value
    let type = generateDate()

    // now you can pass it
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: type, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))

    //...
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks - that worked perfectly - very helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear it.